# Protect Video File From Direct External Download

Tags: php

I have two domains. One is domain1.com and domain2.com. 
All my video files are hosted on domain2.com. 
Now I want people who visits domain1.com can download videos linked to domain2.com but people from direct download (domain2.com) links should not be able to download that file.

So, Please help in detail as I have low knowledge of PHP.

Comment: Place your file outside domain root (php-include folder is OK) and serve it throu php code only.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options checking the [http referer](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/) or proxy the video thru php and check some kind of cross domain token like OAuth2.